# Comparing two binary trees non-recursively

Tags: c

Can I test non-recursively if two binary trees are equal or not?

The maximum number of nodes is 2^16 (=65356) and I have very small memory to work with.

The tree structure:

```
typedef struct tip_arbore
{
     int val;
     struct tip_arbore *s;
     struct tip_arbore *d;
} Arbore;
```

If I can not, how can I set the application to work with more memory(it's a console application)? I have multiple trees but the sum of all nodes is 2^16, but I have for every tree an array of 16 char.

The memory is small so I don't think I can compare them recursively.

Comment: Any recursion can be unrolled to an iterative algorithm. It's a mathematical theorem. So the answer is YES.

Comment: can you tell my how?

Comment: Perhaps use a queue and breadth-first search? that doesn't require recursion…

Comment: For example here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inorder-tree-traversal-without-recursion-and-without-stack/

Comment: all recursive calls have the language implementation to maintain the stack. if you want to iteratify(any good word?) it, you just need to maintain a explicit stack yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, any binary tree can be implemented as an array. You just need to transform it to an array and compare each elements with each other on the same index.

Edit:
If the tree is not already implemented, check http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~holte/T26/tree-as-array.html or http://algoviz.org/OpenDSA/Books/OpenDSA/html/CompleteTree.html for some insight about how to do it.

Comment: A better answer would probably at least put some pseudocode to show an example of how to do this.